# PHP locked when using jQuery ajax with Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Having a small issue that I can't figure out.
I've made a small Wordpress plugin for a client that uses a class as the backend, and some jQuery to do some front end stuff.

The plugin is to export some data from a csv to a table in the database, usually about 20 csv files each time.

Each csv has a couple things done with it, and I've added a field in the table called "step".
Each time something completes on the csv, a row is updated, and the "step" field is increase by 1.

Here's my problem.
Inside the class there is another function "checkSteps" that is called via jQuery ajax to check the process of the csv steps.

I've been noticing that the ajax checking stops until the the php process has completed on all the csv files. Is this a mysql INSERT locking issue?

Update---

```
$wpdb->update( $this->table_name, array( 
        'step' => $database_data['step']
    ),

    array(
        'id' => $database_data['id']
    )
);
```

Monitor---

```
public function monitorCsv($ids){
        global $wpdb;
        $data = explode('-',$ids);

        $db_id = $data[0];
        $file_id = $data[1];        

        if($db_id !== 'null'){
            $db_step = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
                "
                    SELECT step 
                    FROM $this->table_name 
                    WHERE id = %d
                ", 
                $db_id
            ) );
            echo $db_step;
        }

        if($file_id !== 'null'){
            $file_step = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
                "
                    SELECT step 
                    FROM $this->table_name 
                    WHERE id = %d
                ", 
                $file_id
            ) );        
            echo '-'.$file_step;
        }       

    }
```

Check---

```
j('.domonitor').each(function(){
    var ids = j(this).attr('id');

    data = {            
        action: 'csv_do_ajax',
        callback: 'monitorCsv',
        data: ids                               
    };
    j.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){alert(response);});

    });
```

Comment: Need to see some code!

Comment: Neither MyISAM nor InnoDB will lock the table when simply reading from it. However...it will lock the table when you have to update the step field. This is problematic in your scenario because ajax calls are asynchronous by default, and common browsers allow 2 HTTPD connections simultaneously. Your `$.each` iterator is going to fire `2 times instantly` and then will keep performing calls thereafter, maintaining 2 threads the entire time until the iteration is complete. That being said, I'm not even sure it's a locking issue, unfortunately. Use a `$_SESSION` to test, same problem?

Comment: I got rid of the .each, tried with $_SESSION. Same problem.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy When you mentioned $_SESSION I remembered that session data will lock a php file from secondary access. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Turns out because I was firing the ajax method through Wordpress' admin_ajax method, the session variables were locking down the php class.

What I did was put `session_destroy();` in my class's construct method.
**I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS**

However, Wordpress doesn't use sessions by default, and I haven't used them on my theme or anything.